# Missing SQLite.Net.Plaform.XamarinIOS assembly

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I'm working on POC project for android and iOS.
Setup:

- Xamarin.Forms (current version 2.0.1)
- MvvmCross (current version 4.0.0-beta8)

I'm trying to add support for sqlite via:

- MvvmCross.Plugin.SQLitePCL (v 4.0.0-beta8)
- SQLite.Net.Async-PCL (v 3.1.1)
- SQLite.net-PCL (v 3.1.1)

Android application works perfectly fine under this configuration, however on the first use of

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection
```

I get following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinIOS, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.

Anybody knows how to fix it or how to find a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the iOS version is based on monotouch instead of Xamarin.iOS. There  is an issue for that: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1181#issuecomment-173034613

This also has been fixed recently: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/pull/51

Next release it will work like expected.

Comment: Yeah, I've fixed it with adding reference to this project